# How do you cache database queries with Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a server on GCR and it pings a db when called. I was thinking of just adding a simple mechanism for cacheing like

```
var lastDBUpdate int
var lastCache int
if lastDBUpdate > lastCache {
  lastCache = now
  return newResults
} else {
  return cachedResults
}
// endpoints that modify the db update the lastDBUpdate global var
```

This would work if there was only one container (i.e. while my backend has little load), but as my app grows and multiple containers are created, the lastDBUpdate and lastCache variables will be out of sync amongst the different containers. So how can I cache db reads with GCR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Memorystore.

Here is a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-cloud-run) how to connect to a Redis instance from Cloud Run.